# Symfony compile annotated classes

Tags: symfony, symfony-dependency-injection

I'm interested in `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension::getAnnotatedClassesToCompile()` method. If I understand it correctly, you can `addAnnotatedClassesToCompile()` an array of classes (which uses annotations) namespaces. Then during cache warmup all these classes annotations become warmed up. Am I right or something is missing?

If its correct, then why symfony adds `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController`, `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller` to annotated classes? I cant find any annotations in it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/extension.html#adding-classes-to-compile

> If some class extends from other classes, all its parents are automatically included in the list of classes to compile.

As your controllers will extend `Controller` or `AbstractController` that means these will always be checked for annotations so it makes sense to cache the fact they have none. Adding them to `addAnnotatedClassesToCompile` ensures this is done even if you didn't dump an optimized autoloader.